# sublime text 3 & haskell : change compilation directory

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use sublime text 3 on linux mint 17.3, with the haskell plugin.

I opened a directory containing a haskell file (.hs) and I edited it, but when I hit CTRL+B to launch it, it is run correctly but I don't see the binaries file produced in the folder of the source file.

do you know:
- where the files are?
- how I can change this setting?(I searched in the settings but without success)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl + b` doesnt produce binaries, it runs `runhaskell` instead. If you want to create binaries you have to define your own Sublime's build system. To do so use `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System ...` and use any python script you want. More info about build systems can be found in Sublime's manual.